# Prolog gives error undefined procedure

Tags: prolog

I am new in Prolog, but i can't run any procedure from file. 
I have mac os x mountain lion and swipl in /opt/local/bin.
script name is 'prolog' and it's in same directory like swipl.

```
muz(petr).
muz(pavel).
muz(jan).

zena(petra).
zena(pavla).
zena(martina).

potomek(pavel, petr).
potomek(jan, pavel).
potomek(petra, jan).

vzdaleny_potomek(A,B):=potomek(A,B).
vzadelny_potomek(A,B):=vzdaleny_potomek(B,C).
```

In terminal, i first run swipl and then type `consult(prolog)`, it compiles ok, but then when i want run for example `vzdaleny_potomek(petr, pavel)`, it gives me error

**ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: vzdaleny_potomek/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)**

Comment: If SWI-Prolog is installed properly (it probably is), it will be on your $PATH and you don't need to be in the same directory to start it. Actually, if it wasn't on your $PATH, you would have to type `./swipl` even if you were in the same directory. Use `echo $PATH` to see your $PATH, and put your source files somewhere in your home directory. Just a suggestion.

Comment: there is some strange here, after correction suggested by Boris: `vzadelny_potomek(A,B):-vzdaleny_potomek(B,C).`. Two singletons !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your predicate definition is wrong. This: `:=` should be this instead:`:-`.